# CodeChef Daily Train Wrong Answer

Tags: c++

So, in the last contest on CodeChef (February Cook-Off) I had what I thought was a working algorithm for this problem within about 15 minutes, but couldn't get the right answer. I tried forever, I've checked multiple things, I don't understand where my mistake is. My general algorithm matches the editorial for the problem, but I have a bug somewhere I can't find I guess.

Link to the problem - http://www.codechef.com/problems/daily

It's in C++. Code is below. Basically I'm just reading in number of tickets, number of cars, iterating through cars. Read the string, decrement an array of compartments, do the combination (choose) on the compartments, add to output, done.

Works fine on all the test cases and on a few I came up with. There's a few unneeded things in there that are just part of my template for CodeChef.

Any help is appreciated.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <time.h>
#include <string>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;

const double PI=2*acos(0.0);
#define sqr(x) ((x)*(x))
#define min(a,b) ((a)<(b)?(a):(b))
#define max(a,b) ((a)>(b)?(a):(b))



int factorial(int input){
    int output = 1;
    while(input>1){
        output*=input--;
    }
    return output;
}

int choose(int n, int k){
    int output = 0;
    output = factorial(n)/(factorial(k)*factorial(n-k));
    return output;
}

int main(){

#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    clock_t tStart = clock();
    freopen("in.txt","r",stdin);
    //freopen("out.txt","w",stdout);
    //freopen("time.txt","w",stderr);
#endif

    int tickets;
    cin >> tickets;
    int cars;
    cin >> cars;
    string input;
    int output = 0;
    int compartments[9];
    while(cars-->0){
        for(int i = 0;i<9;i++){
            compartments[i] = 6;
        }
        cin >> input;
        for(int i = 0;i<=35;i++){
            compartments[i/4] -= (input.at(i)-48);
        }
        for(int i = 36;i<=53;i++){
            compartments[8-((i-36)/2)] -=(input.at(i)-48);
        }
        for(int i = 0;i<9;i++){
            output+=choose(compartments[i],tickets);
        }

    }

    cout << output;

#ifndef ONLINE_JUDGE
    fprintf(stderr,"Completed in %.0f msec\n",(double)(clock()-tStart));
#endif

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Alright, so I found the answer, but I don't know why. I decided the problem had to be in my choose function, so I tried only calling it when I knew it wouldn't return 0 (i.e., n>=k). That worked. But I don't understand why. If n<k, I would get n!/(k!*1). The 1 is because if input<=1, my factorial outputs 1. The factorial of a negative number isn't defined, and 0 is defined as 1. Therefore, since it isn't defined, returning 1 doesn't affect my choose function. small/large is less than 1, which should round to 0 in int. My function returns 0, no harm. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So the correct code is below.

Inside the while loop, when I do the output+=, I make a small change.

```
if(compartments[i]>=tickets){
  output+=choose(compartments[i],tickets);
}
```

The problem is that my choose function doesn't handle (at least) one case correctly. If compartments[i] = 0 and tickets = 1, the answer should be 0, because the ways to choose 0 things from 1 thing is 0. However, factorial of 0 and 1 are both 1, and factorial (in my function) of -1 (0-1) is also 1, so my choose returns 1/(1*1). Oops. Not sure why it took me so long to find this. I never tested that case. Sorry for the wasted time, I'm still learning.